# Group By Report With Column From Different Dataset in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have 2 Datasets. Dataset 1- SQL Server which has columns such as Incidentid,assignedto,ApplicationName. Now I have another Dataset2 which is a sharepoint list which categorizes these applicationnames into pillars. I was able to use lookup and display the pillarname against the application name but now I want to be able to Group by Pillar and show a report containing all incidents in that parituclar pillar. A pillar is nothing but a group of similar applications and we have multiple pillars.The report should look something like:

Pillar A   IncidentId ApplicationName Assignedperson
           IncidentId ApplicationName Assignedperson

Pillar B   IncidentId ApplicationName Assignedperon
           IncidentId ApplicationName Assignedperon
           IncidentId ApplicationName Assignedperon

Is it possible in SSRS 2008 R2? What are my options? Obviously I tried doing it and it gives error.Re Fields withing the current dataset scope.

I also tried using lookup in the group but no help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did some testing in SSRS 2008 r2 and I was able to create a parent group within a table and use a lookup function in the group by expression for that group. The data was represented accurately and I didn't get any errors. I was working with two datasets that were both created using queries to a sql server database, so it is possible that the SharePoint list is the issue - I think that's probably worth testing to make sure that it isn't just your expression that is causing issues.

Comment: Thanks TPhe, I was able to figure it out when I tried again, I also used the lookup expression in the group by expression to set up the group . I think the issue was when I was trying to drag the column to the group by pane it showed error, but when I created it from the report body it worked fine. Weird!!!

Comment: No problem, glad you were able to get it working. If you feel that this was a useful answer, you can mark it as the correct one. If not, you can edit your original post with a description of what you found the problem to be and how you corrected it to help anyone with a similar issue in the future.